# Prior art for US 2011/0242130?

Tags: prior-art-request, us20110242130

Does anyone have any prior art for US 20110242130? This publication is about a composite image production process.

Casio Computer Co.;
filed: March 30, 2011

http://appft1.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO1&Sect2=HITOFF&d=PG01&p=1&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsrchnum.html&r=1&f=G&l=50&s1=%2220110242130%22.PGNR.&OS=DN/20110242130&RS=DN/20110242130

Comment: Where have you looked? Please read [What should an ideal prior art request look like?](http://meta.patents.stackexchange.com/q/47) as well as the [faq#good-question] and [Are questions of the form 'Can anyone find prior art for patent X' on topic?](http://meta.patents.stackexchange.com/q/34).

Answer (score 1):

On Jan. 8th 2013 the examiner issued a non final rejection on this application as being anticipated by [2004/009608 Matsumoto](http://www.google.com/patents/US20040096085?pg=PA1&dq=2004/0096085%20Matsumoto&hl=en&sa=X&ei=JSsEUeeuB-eWiAKw_IGQDw&sqi=2&pjf=1&ved=0CDYQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=2004/0096085%20Matsumoto&f=false)  and on other grounds. You can look this up in public PAIR at the USPTO.